# Last ItemName() in SimpleDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-simpledb

I am trying to find the ITEMNAME() for the last item available in SimpleDB. I could n't find any resource which could guide me to get the result ?  Is there any function or query available to get the last inserted item's name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are inserting `itemName()` is `sequence` or `order` then only you can get the last inserted `itemName()` by using the below `query`

```
select * from `domainname` where itemName() is not null order by itemName() desc limit 1
```

Comment: This is fine . But there is no method available to pick only the last item name , right ? .

Comment: Yes. There is no way to get the last inserted `itemName()`. The above query is actually sorting record by `item names` in descending order to get the last `itemName()`.

Comment: Thanks , I just wanted to confirm the same